# how to make text input and button the same height when assigning the text input fixed font-size?

Tags: css, button, text, height, font-size

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

form {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

form input {
    width: 90%;
    font-size: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

form button {
    width: 9%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form>
        <input id="m" type="text">
        <button>POST</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd like to create a simple text and button page. The requirement is:

1. The text and button are both on the bottom,
2. The text and button have the same height and are aligned,
3. The text has fixed font-size (e.g. 50px)

How can I achieve that? The text is much bigger than the button now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flexbox can do that:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
form {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
}
form input {
  width: 90%;
  font-size: 50px;
}
form button {
  width: 9%;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="m" type="text">
  <button>POST</button>
</form>
```